# Strange behaviour in GHCi using Cloud Haskell Platform

Tags: haskell, network-programming, ghci, cloud-haskell

Following the tutorials (http://haskell-distributed.github.io), this code – after calling `dev` in GHCi – lets one CPU core spin up to 100% and stays at that level indefinitely. This seem to happen due to the call to `closeTransport`.

However, evaluating the code in GHCi line by line, does not show this effect. So where does the difference come from and how can I correctly clean up?

```
import Network.Transport (closeTransport)
import Network.Transport.TCP (createTransport, defaultTCPParameters)
import Control.Distributed.Process.Node (newLocalNode, closeLocalNode, initRemoteTable)

dev :: IO ()
dev = do
  Right t <- createTransport "localhost" "9000" defaultTCPParameters
  n <- newLocalNode t initRemoteTable
  -- do the work
  closeLocalNode n -- <- doesn't affect the observed behaviour
  closeTransport t
```